# Summation of time complexity Brute force string match computation

Tags: algorithm, sum, analysis

I am trying to solve the summation computation of the time complexity of brute force string match.

The algorithm is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-m; i++) {
         int j = 0;
         while (j < m && t[i+j] == p[j]) {
                   j++;
         }
         if (j == m) return i;
}
          System.out.println(‘‘Element not found.’’);
 return -1;
```

I have attached my unfinished computation and still trying to solve it. Can someone tell me if I am doing it correctly or wrong? Should I continue getting the answer on the way I solve it? I apologize asking but I am really having a hard time to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can break your calculation into the following steps:

1- The for loop iterates from `i = 0 to i < n - m`, incrementing `i` by 1 in each iteration. This loop runs `(n - m)` times.

2- Inside the for loop, there is a while loop that runs until `j < m` and the condition `t[i+j] == p[j]` is satisfied. In the worst case where there is no match, the while loop will run `m` times.

3- The condition `if (j == m)` checks if the entire pattern `p` has been matched. If so, the function returns the current value of `i`; otherwise, it continues to the next iteration of the for loop.

4- If the for loop completes without finding a match, the code prints "Element not found" and returns -1.

In the worst case scenario, the algorithm will iterate `(n - m)` times in the for loop, and in each iteration, the while loop will run `m` times. Therefore, the overall time complexity of the code is `O((n - m) * m)`.

In the case `m << n` time complexity can be approximated to `O(n*m)`.

Comment: @MBo Oops, I made a mistake for `m<<n`. Yes, it is `O(n*m)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the very informative answer!